# ¿A qué se debe esto dentro de mi grid css?

Tags: css, html5, vue.js, ionic, ionic-framework

Estoy tratando de acomodar la información de una lista dentro de un grid, la información esta separada en 3 columnas y una fila, el dato "hora" no tiene  todo el espacio de la pantalla o el espacio que le asigne; me gustaría saber en que momento del código se activa ese espacio, como podría quitarlo o si debo buscar en otra parte del proyecto (ya que el código no es de mi propiedad es del equipo de desarrollo anterior y he estado solucionando errores de estructura)

Imagen de como se ve al examinar el elemento:

[image: Así se ve al examinar el objeto]

Anexo el código completo del archivo al que corresponden los elementos de esta lista (se usa Ionic para este proyecto), supondría que lo importante se encuentra en el style

```
<template>
  <div v-if="!isLoading">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item
        v-for="correspondence in correspondenceList"
        :key="correspondence.id_recibida"
        @click="goToCorrespondenceDetail(correspondence.id_recibida)"
      >
        <div class="grid">
          <div>
            <img
              src="assets_2/img/internal_icon/recibida_interna.png"
              class="icons_2"
              alt="imagen_porDefecto_recibidaParteInterna"
              id="open-modal"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="letras">
            <h2 class="letras-blod">{{ correspondence.resumen }}</h2>
            <p class="font-normal">2020-12-3</p>
            <!-- <h3>{{ correspondence.fradica }}</h3> -->
            <p class="uppercase">{{ correspondence.remitente_nombre }}</p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p class="font-normal letra-hora">
              {{ correspondence.hradica }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
  <!-- Skeleton screen -->
  <div v-if="isLoading">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item v-for="skeleton in 10" :key="skeleton">
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="icons_2">
            <ion-skeleton-text :animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text>
          </div>
          <div class="letras">
            <ion-label>
              <h2>
                <ion-skeleton-text :animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text>
              </h2>
              <p>
                <ion-skeleton-text :animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text>
              </p>
              <p>
                <ion-skeleton-text :animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text>
              </p>
            </ion-label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p class="letra-hora">
              <ion-skeleton-text :animated="true"></ion-skeleton-text>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
  <ion-infinite-scroll
    @ionInfinite="getCorrespondenceReceived($event, true)"
    threshold="50px"
    id="infinite-scroll"
    :disabled="isDisabled"
  >
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
      loading-spinner="crescent"
      loading-text="Obteniendo registros..."
    >
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</template>

<script>
import {
  IonList,
  IonLabel,
  IonItem,
  IonInfiniteScroll,
  IonInfiniteScrollContent,
  IonSkeletonText,
  useBackButton,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { CorrespondenceReceived } from "@/services/correspondence";
import { backButtonHandler, isAuthorized } from "@/lib/helpers";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
const { App } = Plugins;
export default {
  components: {
    IonList,
    IonLabel,
    IonItem,
    IonInfiniteScroll,
    IonInfiniteScrollContent,
    IonSkeletonText,
  },
  setup() {
    const correspondenceList = ref([]);
    const isLoading = ref(false);
    const isDisabled = ref(false);
    const router = useRouter();
    const currentPage = ref(1);
    const perPage = ref(40);
    const lastPage = ref(10);
    const store = useStore();
    async function getCorrespondenceReceived(ev, isByScroll = false) {
      try {
        if (isByScroll) {
          currentPage.value++;
        } else {
          isLoading.value = true;
          currentPage.value = 1;
        }
        if (currentPage.value > lastPage.value) {
          isDisabled.value = true;
          throw new Error("No hay más registros");
        }
        const res = await CorrespondenceReceived(
          perPage.value,
          currentPage.value,
          store.state.filterData.resume,
          store.state.filterData.date
        );
        lastPage.value = res.data.last_page;
        if (res.data.data == undefined) {
          throw new Error("No se encontraron registros");
        }
        if (res.data.data.length > 0) {
          for (let x = 0; x < res.data.data.length; x++) {
            correspondenceList.value.push(res.data.data[x]);
          }
        }
        if (ev != undefined) {
          ev.target.complete();
        }
        isLoading.value = false;
      } catch (error) {
        isLoading.value = false;
        isAuthorized(error.message);
      }
    }
    // go to correspondence detail
    function goToCorrespondenceDetail(id) {
      router.push("/correspondence/" + id);
    }
    getCorrespondenceReceived();
    useBackButton(10, () => {
      if (backButtonHandler()) {
        App.exitApp();
      }
    });
    return {
      isDisabled,
      isLoading,
      correspondenceList,
      goToCorrespondenceDetail,
      getCorrespondenceReceived,
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.icons_2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 85.33px;
  height: 85.33px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 912px) {
  .icons_2 {
    width: 85.33px;
    height: 85.33px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .icons_2 {
    width: 51.16px;
    height: 51.16px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .icons_2 {
    width: 52.16px;
    height: 52.16px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
  .icons_2 {
    width: 21.16px;
    height: 21.16px;
  }
}
.letra-hora {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font: 14px;
}
.letras {
  text-align: left;
}
.letras-blod {
  font: 14px;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 700px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 75px 700px 70px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 75px 450px 80px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 912px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80px 500px 80px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 350px 80px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 245px 70px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 45px 185px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 120px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 393px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 180px 70px;
    grid-template-rows: 120px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 280px) {
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30px 175px 20px;
    grid-template-rows: 130px;
    row-gap: 2px;
  }
  .letra-hora {
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font: 3px;
  }
  .letras {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
      "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif,
      "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol",
      "Noto Color Emoji";
  }
  .letras-blod {
    font: 3px;
    font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
      "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif,
      "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol",
      "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
}
</style>
```

Editado: logré solucionar el problema aplicando la siguiente clase, que encierra el div padre de las columnas correspondientes, prácticamente esto se genera por lo que se comentaba en las respuestas de la pregunta; que ningún contenedor estaba tomando el tamaño máximo del apartado, se pueden variar el valor del "justify-content" según lo requerido por el desarrollador, en mi caso quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
.classFix{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    flex-direction: inherit;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

(Esta imagen es de otro apartado, pero prácticamente funciona igual).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es devido a que ninguno de los contenedores dentro del grid se le ha dicho que abarque el tamaño maximo que pueda en su lugar simplemente usa el tamaño minimo requerido, la solucion puede pasar por hacer que uno de los 3 contenedores coja el tamañano maximo que pueda o hacer que el padre con la clase grid los alinee con el espacio maximo  -->

```
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-between;
```